# Business Application Studio: Create Transport Request for UI5 Application

Tags: sap-fiori, sap-business-application-studio

How can I manually create a TR for my UI5-Application? During deployment with '`npm run deploy`' an error pops up that I have to create TR.

Values in file `ui5-deploy.yaml`:

```
    - name: deploy-to-abap
      afterTask: generateCachebusterInfo
      configuration:
        target:
          destination: abap-cloud-default_abap-trial-XXXXXXXXtrial_XXXXXX-aptchj15-dev
          url: https://XXX.abap.us10.hana.ondemand.com
          scp: true
        app:
          name: ZLM_CONNECTIONS
          package: ZBS_TH_FIORI_APPS
          transport: REPLACE_WITH_TRANSPORT
        exclude:
          - /test/`
```

What was not successful:
I recreated Deployment Config File with following Problems:

"Create new" dont work, I receive error Message:
*Create new Transport Request failed. Please enter Transport Request manually.*
[image]

"Create during deployment": Error Status 500: Creation of TR not possible during Deployment
[image]